# Search for data in CSV with input form

Tags: php

I have a script like that:

```
    $value = $_POST['number']; // searching with input named number 

    $csv = array();
    $file = fopen('data.csv', 'r');

    while (($result = fgetcsv($file)) !== false)
    {
        $csv[] = $result;
    }

    if (in_array($value, $csv)) {
        echo "found";
    }
    else {
        echo "not found";
    }

    fclose($file);
```

Basically, I always get an answer "not found". Is there any way I could search in CSV file like that?

Comment: `$csv` is an array of array, each element will be a line of the CSV file.  So you will need to search each element of `$csv` for the value - unless you know which column the value is going to be in.

Comment: Do you have an example format for your CSV file?

Comment: my csv headings are: "ico, customer id, loginName" and I would like to search for certain customer id which is 6 digit number

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, in_array only support single dimension array. And your `$csv` is 2-dimensional. If you have multiple rows of numbers in the CSV file, you'd probably need to search them row by row.

```
<?php

$value = $_POST['number']; // searching with input named number 

$csv = array();
$file = fopen('data.csv', 'r');

while (($result = fgetcsv($file)) !== false)
{
    $csv[] = $result;
}
fclose($file);

$found = false;
foreach ($csv as $row) {
    if (in_array($value, $row)) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if ($found) {
    echo "found";
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to iterate twice, you can get a line from csv and immediately search for `$value`:

```
$value = $_POST['number']; // searching with input named number 

$file = fopen('data.csv', 'r');

$found = false;
while (($result = fgetcsv($file)) !== false)
{
    if (in_array($value, $result)) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($found) {
    echo "found";
}
else {
    echo "not found";
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: I tried your code, but when I search for valid number which is in CSV file, I always get "not found".

Comment: Provide search value and `$result` in which you expect this value to be present.

Comment: I'm searching for the number, for example, "420221", which is in the second column in my CSV file. Columns are "ico, customerId, login".

Comment: Here's a simple fiddle - https://3v4l.org/Zq57o. You have to check what `$value` and `$result` on each `while` iteration you have and confirm that in one of `$result`s you have the required `$value`.